# Load on startup of a servlet/ controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Is it possible to load on startup a server, when running as spring boot application??

I tried with this,

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sixdee.controller.TestController
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

but this servlet is not coming up, while I am running. Any solutions??

Comment: Do we need to use the Dispatcher servlet??

Comment: Just add the servlet as a bean and wrap it in a `ServletRegistrationBean`. If you would have read [this section of the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans), you would have known.

Comment: thanks, how can we use the ServletConfig init parameters?? In my present web.xml, I have these and my startup class is taking these values. How can i  access them?? Do u have any idea? @M.Deinum

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletRegistrationBean.html).